# How to route messages in RabbitMQ receiver?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, messaging, spring-amqp

I would like to process incoming messages differently basing on the message header. How to implement it efficiently in RabbitMQ?

My listener is listenining to messages coming from presence.queue channels. The message header KEY has different keys: key1, key2. Messages with key1 should be processed by messageService.method1, messages with key2 should be processed with messageService.method2.

Here is the code I am playing with but obviously it is wrong. I probably should route messages from presence.queue to first.queue and second.queue ?

```
<!-- RECEIVER -->

<rabbit:queue id="presence.queue" name="presence"  durable="true"/>
<rabbit:queue id="first.queue" name="first"/>
<rabbit:queue id="second.queue" name="second"/>

<rabbit:direct-exchange name="presence.direct" durable="true" >
   <rabbit:bindings>
      <rabbit:binding queue="presence.queue" key="key1"/>
      <rabbit:binding queue="presence.queue" key="key2"/>
   </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:direct-exchange>

<!-- RabbitMQ Asynchronous Receiver from PRESENCE_ENGINE queue -->
<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory" acknowledge="auto" > 
    <rabbit:listener queues="first.queue" ref="messageService" method="method1" />
    <rabbit:listener queues="second.queue" ref="messageService" method="method2" />
</rabbit:listener-container>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need presence.queue? Just bind your consumer queues with the appropriate routing key. If you want to use message headers for routing, use a Headers Exchange.

See [Getting Started](http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html) and [Headers Exchange](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html).

Comment: Other modules submit messages to the presence.queue that is why and I am forced to use it. Previously I used spring integration and message router that routed the received messages to appropriate channels. Now, I have to find the similar solution with AMQP.

Answer (score 1):

Correction. Producers send messages to the exchange, not the queue. Come back, please, to the AMQP theory.

They may send Messages with the same routing key as well, but as Gary suggests, you can use **Headers Exchange** and build binding to your queues by some value from MessageProperties. 
Especially you already have that value.

There is nohing to change on producer side. But from other side: you are the server (consumer) and everything in your hadns: you can configure AMQP routing as it would be comfortably for you.

That's why AMQP is better than JMS!